# Python regex compile

Tags: python, regex

The programmer who wrote the following line probably uses a python package called [`regex`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex).

```
UNIT = regex.compile("(?:{A}(?:'{A})?)++|-+|\S".format(A='\p{Word_Break=ALetter}'))
```

Can some one help explain what `A='\p{Word_Break=ALetter}'` and `-+` means?

Comment: I've removed the `pypi` tag; the module may be distributed through pypi, but this question is not about `pypi` itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\p{property=value}` operator matches on unicode codepoint properties, and is documented on the package index page you linked to:

> - Unicode codepoint properties, including scripts and blocks
>
>   ```
>   \p{property=value}; \P{property=value}; \p{value} ; \P{value}
>   ```

The entry matches any unicode character whose codepoint has a [`Word_Break` property](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/auxiliary/WordBreakProperty.txt) with the value `ALetter` (there are currently 24941 matches in the Unicode codepoint database, see the [Unicode Text Segmentation, Word Boundaries chapter specifiation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries) for details).

The example you gave also uses standard python [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) to interpolate a partial expression into the regular expression being compiled. The "{A}" part is just a placeholder for the `.format(A='...')` part to fill. The end result is:

```
"(?:\p{Word_Break=ALetter}(?:'\p{Word_Break=ALetter})?)++|-+|\S"
```

The `-+` sequence just matches 1 or more `-` dashes, just like in the python `re` module expressions, it is not anything special, really.

Now, the `++` *before* that is more interesting. It's a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), and using it prevents the regex matcher from trying out all possible permutations of the pattern. It's a performance optimization, one that prevents [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) issues.

Comment: Is Word_Break property something like comma, proclamation? I don't fully understand the linked page.

Comment: @juju: `Word_Break` classifies code points into items that form words and things that come in between, so that software dealing with texts can determine where words start and end in any script. `ALetter` is one such class, mostly alphabetic characters.

Comment: Is the linked page introducing varied languages that `Word_Break` covers? Would you give me an example in English?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what `Word_Break=ALetter` means in detail either; I imagine it is a more inclusive `\w` group in this case supporting more Unicode scripts.